# Network socket issues in a high load Python service

Tags: python, docker, networking, udp

I have a Python service running in a Docker container. The service communicates with several other services using different methods, including:

1. Regular HTTP/HTTPS calls.
2. Accessing the database through a Unix socket.
3. Sending UDP metrics.

Occasionally, I encounter various network exceptions, such as:

```
OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.6432" failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

This error occurs when querying PostgreSQL database via a Unix socket.

```
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

This error occurs when sending UDP metrics.

I suspect that these exceptions are not random connection issues but rather a result of my service hitting some system limit. This suspicion arises because I have similar services that use the same environment and connect to the same database, but they do not experience this problem.

The most puzzling aspect is the BrokenPipeError, which, as I understand, indicates that the remote server closed the connection. However, this error message doesn't make sense to me in the context of UDP, where connections are not maintained.

Here is a sample of my UDP sender code:

```
family = socket.getaddrinfo(host, DEFAULT_PORT_UDP)[0][0]
with socket.socket(family, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
   s.sendto(metric.encode('utf-8'), (host, DEFAULT_PORT_UDP))
```

And here is the exception stack trace:

```
BrokenPipeError
[Errno 32] Broken pipe
family: <AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>
s: <socket.socket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=0>
```

I have attempted to mitigate the workload by dividing the service into smaller services, which appears to be associated with a decrease in the frequency of errors. However, I have not been able to completely eliminate the issue.

In an effort to simulate the UDP BrokenPipe error, I have experimented with various approaches in a different environment. This includes increasing concurrency within the Python process to investigate if concurrency-related issues are causing the problem. Additionally, I have made adjustments to operating system-level configurations such as reducing the maximum number of open files (ulimit) and modifying other settings. Unfortunately, these attempts have resulted in different errors rather than reproducing the desired error.

What could be the reason and how do I troubleshoot it?